# Difference between DbSet.Add(entity) and entity.State = EntityState.Added

Tags: entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between IDbSet.Add and DbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082922/what-is-the-difference-between-idbset-add-and-dbentityentry-state-entitystate)

What's the difference between [DbSet.Add(entity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) vs [entity.State = EntityState.Added](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)? I some examples using both to add an entity to DbContext but not sure which is the preferred one.

I saw some test the "**Detached**" condition and decide which to use in their repository implementation.

```
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        var entry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
    }
```

Anyone idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any difference between either of these options as under the hood they are both   calling the same method (ie AddObject on an ObjectContext).