# Cascade Delete with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have these two models:

```
public partial class Country
{
        public Country()
        {
            this.Dinners = new HashSet<Dinner>();
        }

        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Dinner> Dinners { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class Dinner
{
        public Dinner()
        {
            this.TRsvps = new HashSet<TRsvp>();
        }

        public int DinnerID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string HostedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CountryID { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

I got a bit confused on how Entity Framework will act when a user tries to delete a parent entity (in our case it is the `Country` entity) that has child records (`Dinners`).

For example if I have the following code inside my mvc action method:-

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Country country = db.Countries.Find(id);
    db.Countries.Remove(country);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And exception will be raised if I try to remove a country which has dinners, which sounds valid.

I tried modifying my code as follow, by including the `Dinners` when retrieving the `Country` object:

```
Country country = db.Countries.Include(a => a.Dinners).Single(a2 => a2.CountryId = id);
db.Countries.Remove(country);
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

No exception will be raised, so I thought that EF would have deleted the child dinners, but what happens is that it updates the `countryID` FK inside the `Dinners` table to be null.... (`Cascade Set to Null`)

I tried looping over the `Dinners` collection as follows:

```
 public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
 {
     Country country2 = db.Countries.Find(id) ;

     foreach(var d in country2.Dinners)
     {
         db.Dinners.Remove(d);
     }

     db.Countries.Remove(country2);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

but this raised the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation
>   may not execute.

I realized that I should explicitly call the `.Tolist()` on the foreach to get the parent and all its children deleted as follows:

```
 foreach(var d in country2.Dinners.ToList())
```

Can anyone advice if I getting things wrong, or this is the only way to support cascade on delete using EF ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled cascaded deletes on your model?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your deletes to cascade automatically, in your [OnModelCreating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx) method, you need to manually enable it:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Comment: but this will affect all the models is this correct ? while in my case only admin users are able to perform such a deletion, and normal users will not be able to delete parent records unless they do not contain child records,,

Comment: so i need to control this on action method basis ,,

Comment: Yes, that's true. But you should have the correct security on the action method anyway.

Comment: yes i have applied a CustomeAuthorizarion attribute so users with admin roles will only be able to call an action method that do a Cascade delete..

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you need to manually enable cascade on delete if you make the foreign key an `int` rather than an `int?`

Comment: @Colin Making it a nullable int will make the relationship optional though, not necessarily what is required.

Comment: Yes, my point is that it is already nullable and should be changed to non-nullable to make it a required relationship - which is cascade on delete by default

Comment: aha ok you pointed out an important thing, but then the delete will have a Cascade delete when i use the .Include ? is this correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing the documented behaviour for cascade delete when the foreign key is nullable:

> If a foreign key on the dependent entity is nullable, Code First does
>   not set cascade delete on the relationship, and when the principal is
>   deleted the foreign key will be set to null.

If you want it to cascade delete then the relationship is required and the foreign key should not be nullable. Change `public Nullable<int> CountryID { get; set; }` to `public int CountryID { get; set; }`

Reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete

**Additional info following your comment**
You don't have to `.Include` to get cascade delete to work on required relationships *i.e. once you have made the foreign key non-nullable*. I am sure of this because that is how my application works.

I think you are observing that `Remove` marks your entire object graph for removal - whether required or not - in the same way that `Add` marks the entire graph for insertion. NB - I am not 100% sure of this bit so you should test this before you rely on it.

Further reading here:

[using Dbset.Add Versus using EntityState.Added](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26613722/150342)

[Why Does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

[What is the difference between IDbSet.Add and DbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9082922/150342)

Comment: but to Cascade delete then i have to use .Include() as follow :- "Country country = db.Countries.Include(a => a.Dinners).Single(a2 => a2.CountryId = id);" , is this correct ?

Comment: i think if you pass the whole object to the POST delete action method including all the Navigation properties, then .Remove will do a cascade on delete,, but in my action method i do not pass the whole object with its navigation properties, i just pass the object ID and then i retrieve it from the db, so i think .Include is required in my case to force cascade on delete,, i need to test this ...

Comment: now if i changed the FK on the dinner table to be int instead of int?, and i wrote the following db.Countries.Remove(country), i will get the following exception ;-Additional information: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must